# Get coordinates from image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a wayfinder app for the library building. I'm developing it using HTML and JavaScript. I've mapped all the coordinates of library rooms on the image, and I'm navigating one object over the image to show the directions, and I'm using `jquery.path` to navigate the object.

But now I want to change the size of the image, I want to make it bigger than earlier, but now have to map all coordinates. :(

Anyone please suggest me another ways to map coordinates quickly.

Comment: it's hard to give and advice w/o seeing the code, but from top of my head you could add 'scale' variable that would be equal to 1 if image is in initial size and will increase accordingly if you make you image bigger...like var scale = img.INITIAL_WIDTH / img.NEW_WIDTH

Comment: Could you please show us your code? What did you try so far?